# How to do condition in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a stored procedure in which I need to implement a conditional `WHERE` clause.

I have a `@name` parameter, `@startdate` and `@enddate` parameters.

How can I write conditions:

- if `@name is null` and `@startdate` & `@enddate` is given then return data for date range.
- if `@name` is given and `@startdate` & `@enddate is null` then return data for the name
- if `@name` and `@startdate` & `@enddate` is given then return data where name **and** date range are evaluated

Here is my current procedure

```
alter procedure dbo.sp_emp
     @name varchar(50),
     @startdate date,
     @enddate date
as 
begin
    select * 
    from employee 
    where 
        Name = @name 
        and dob between @startdate and @enddate
end
```

Comment: I edit your question to make it a bit more clear for everyone. If I misinterpreted your meaning please fix it.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1):

I think `COALESCE` solves your problem.

```
alter procedure dbo.sp_emp
@name varchar(50),
@startdate date,
@enddate date
as 
begin
select * 
from employee 
where Name = (COALESCE(@name, name))
  AND dob between COALESCE(@startdate, dob) and COALESCE(@enddate, dob)
end
```

ISNULL version

```
alter procedure dbo.sp_emp
@name varchar(50),
@startdate date,
@enddate date
as 
begin
select * 
FROM employee 
WHERE Name = ISNULL(@name, name)
  AND dob between ISNULL(@startdate, dob) AND ISNULL(@enddate, dob)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(2048);

SET @query = 'select * from employee where Name = ''' + @name + '''';

IF @startdate IS NOT NULL AND @enddate IS NOT NULL
     SET @query += ' AND dob between ''' + @startdate + ''' and ''' + @enddate '''';

EXECUTE(@query);
```

You should take care yours vars about SQL Injection.